# How to group the rows and get the count based on other column values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table (with name 'jobs') having columns 'ID' and 'Type'. ID column can have same id more than once and the type column with have two values say 'A' and 'B'. I want to get the count of all the ids with type just 'A', with type just 'B' and with type 'A' and 'B' both.

I have tried the below query but it gives the count of type 'A' and type 'B'.

```
SELECT distinct 
       type,
       COUNT( 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY type) AS Count
FROM   jobs
```

Sample Data:

```
ID    Type    
1      A    
1      B    
2      A    
2      B    
3      A    
4      A    
5      A    
6      B    
7      B    
8      B    
9      B
```

Expected Output is:

```
Count of ID’s having just A as type: 3    
Count of ID’s having just B as type : 4    
Count of ID’s having A and B as type : 2
```

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Please add expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Output is simple as below:
Count of Type A : 10
Count of Type B: 15
Count of type A and B : 5
Getting count of type 'A' and 'B' is simple enough, I am confused how to get the count of the ids in table having records for both type 'A' and type 'B' separately

Comment: Your query is almost correct for the first 2 cases, I have to think about 3rd scenario A+B : SELECT distinct 
       type,
       COUNT( DISTINCT ID ) OVER ( PARTITION BY type) AS Count
FROM   jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this.

```
--test data
with jobs(id,type) AS
(
select 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 2, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 2, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 2, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 3, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 3, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 4, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 4, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 5, 'B' FROM DUAL 
) --test data ends
select count(only_a) as "Count of Type A Only",
       count(only_b) as "Count of Type B Only",
       count(both_a_and_b) as "Count of Type A and B both"
FROM
(
SELECT
    ID,
    CASE WHEN MAX(TYPE)  = MIN(TYPE) and MIN(TYPE)  = 'A' THEN 1 END only_a,
    CASE WHEN MAX(TYPE)  = MIN(TYPE) and MIN(TYPE)  = 'B' THEN 1 END only_b,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT TYPE) = 2 THEN 1 END both_a_and_b
FROM jobs
WHERE type in ('A','B')
GROUP BY ID
)s;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b59a7cc28a34dfba7211bbe6db6c8364)

Comment: @ Kaushik Nayak : A & B are the values of the field 'Type'. I just need to aggregate the values based of ids. Please check my expected output.

Comment: @palpras : Have you tried the query on your tables? What output did you get?

Comment: @ Kaushik Nayak . Thanks, I am able to get the required output :)

Comment: @ Kaushik Nayak : Is it feasible to get the same result without using the group by, just thinking from the perspective of making it more performance efficient

Comment: @palpras : There may be, but I don't think they would improve the performance any better and `group by` is the most sensible thing to go for when you have multiple ids to aggregate. One option to speed up the query would be  to add an index on `id,type`. You may ask a separate question if you face performance issues giving the details of the `explain plan` etc as performance purely depends on your data

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select sum(case when num_As > 0 and num_Bs = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_A_only,
       sum(case when num_As = 0 and num_Bs > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_B_only,
       sum(case when num_As > 0 and num_Bs > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_A_and_B       
from (select id,
             sum(case when type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as num_As,
             sum(case when type = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as num_Bs
      from t
      group by id
     ) t;
```

If you want this in separate rows:

```
select (case when num_As > 0 and num_Bs = 0 then 'A_only'
             when num_As = 0 and num_Bs > 0 then 'B_only'
             when num_As > 0 and num_Bs > 0 then 'A_and_B'
        end) as grp,
       count(*)       
from (select id,
             sum(case when type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as num_As,
             sum(case when type = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as num_Bs
      from t
      group by id
     ) t
group by (case when num_As > 0 and num_Bs = 0 then 'A_only'
               when num_As = 0 and num_Bs > 0 then 'B_only'
               when num_As > 0 and num_Bs > 0 then 'A_and_B'
          end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data the below will work as expected:

```
with jobs(id,type) AS
    (
    select 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 2, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 2, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 2, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 3, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 3, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 4, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 4, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 5, 'B' FROM DUAL 
    ) 
    SELECT distinct
            j1.type||j2.type as type,
           COUNT( DISTINCT j1.ID ) OVER ( PARTITION BY j1.type||j2.type) AS Count
    FROM   jobs j1 inner join jobs j2 on j1.id = j2.id and j1.type <= j2.type
```

Answer (score 0):

Get 3 different counters for each case:

```
select 
  (select count(distinct id) from jobs j
   where ((select max(jobs.type) from jobs where jobs.id = j.id) = 'a')
  ) countera,
  (select count(distinct id) from jobs j
   where ((select min(jobs.type) from jobs  where jobs.id = j.id) = 'b')
  ) counterb,
  (select count(distinct id) from jobs j
   where (
      (select min(jobs.type) from jobs  where jobs.id = j.id) = 'a'
      and
      (select max(jobs.type) from jobs  where jobs.id = j.id) = 'b'
    )) counterab
from dual;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=66928b031fb4d19f9f623c3d4500d9ad)

To get 1 row for each counter:

```
select 
  'Count of IDs having just A as type :' descr,
  count(distinct id) counter from jobs j
where ((select max(jobs.type) from jobs where jobs.id = j.id) = 'a')
union all
select
  'Count of IDs having just B as type :' descr,
  count(distinct id) from jobs j
where ((select min(jobs.type) counter from jobs  where jobs.id = j.id) = 'b')
union all
select 
  'Count of IDs having A and B as type :' descr,
  count(distinct id) counter from jobs j
where 
  (
    (select min(jobs.type) from jobs  where jobs.id = j.id) = 'a'
    and
    (select max(jobs.type) from jobs  where jobs.id = j.id) = 'b'
  );
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2c9b206287de038a9913b4af74780e96)

Comment: I am not getting the expected results from your query

Comment: @palpras there are 2 demos where you see the expected results.